# regex assistance

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a semi dynamically generated string. So I can see if its the correct format, then extract the information from it that I need. My Problem is I no matter how hard I try to grasp regex can't fathom it for the life of me. Even with the help of so called generators.

What I have is a couple different strings like the following. `[@img:1234567890]` and `[@user:1234567890]` and `[@file:file_name-with.ext]`. Strings like this pass through are intent on passing through a filter so they can be replaced with links, and or more readable names. But again try as I might I can't come up with a regex for any given one of them.

I am looking for the format: `[@word:]` of which I will strip the [, ], @, and word from the string so I can then turn around an query my DB accordingly for whatever it is and work with it accordingly. Just the regex bit is holding me back.

Comment: try `[@(\w+):(.*)]`. `$1` and `$2` will give you your variables.

Comment: Note that you should rather use a [summary as question title](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help7). If you are more specific there, it gets easier to find for others, and attracts more specific help instead of just anyone curious for mysterious headlines. Eschew relisting tags, redundant pleas for help, question marks without question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by generators.  I always use online matchers to see that my test cases work.  @Virendra almost had it except forgot to escape the `[]` charaters.

```
/\[@(\w+):(.*)\]/
```

You need to start and end with a regex delimeter, in this case the '/' character.

Then we escape the '[]' which is use by regex to match ranges of characters hence the '['.

Next we match a literal '@' symbol.

Now we want to save this next match so we can use it later so we surround it with `()`.

`\w` matches a `word`. Basically any characters that aren't spaces, punctuation, or line characters.

Again match a literal `:`.

Maybe useful to have the second part in a match group as well so `(.*)` will match any character any number of times, and save it for you.

Then we escape the closing `]` as we did earlier.

Since it sounds like you want to use the matches later in a query we can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to save the matches to an array.

```
$pattern = '/\[@(\w+):(.*)\]/';
$subject = '[@user:1234567890]';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Would output

```
array(
    [0] => '[@user:1234567890]', // Full match
    [1] => 'user', // First match
    [2] => '1234567890' // Second match
)
```

An especially helpful tool I've found is [txt2re](http://www.txt2re.com/index-php.php)

Comment: quote unquote generators found via google, where you input a string you wanna match and its suposed to generate you a regex. Which most either dont from what I gather or they only match specifically the string you give, with little room for play outside of that

Comment: To get $1 and $2 respectively I would use preg_match, preg_replace, other? If you had to suggest something?

Comment: @chris added section for `preg_match`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

```
<pre>
<?php

    $subj = 'An image:[@img:1234567890], a user:[@user:1234567890] and a file:[@file:file_name-with.ext]';
    preg_match_all('~(?<match>\[@(?<type>[^:]+):(?<value>[^\]]+)\])~',$subj,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as &$arr) unset($arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3]);
    print_r($matches);

?>
</pre>
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match] => [@img:1234567890]
            [type] => img
            [value] => 1234567890
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match] => [@user:1234567890]
            [type] => user
            [value] => 1234567890
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [match] => [@file:file_name-with.ext]
            [type] => file
            [value] => file_name-with.ext
        )

)
```

And here's a pseudo version of how I would use the `preg_replace_callback()` function:

```
function replace_shortcut($matches) {
    global $users;
    switch (strtolower($matches['type'])) {
        case 'img'  : return '<img src="images/img_'.$matches['value'].'jpg" />';
        case 'file' : return '<a href="files/'.$matches['value'].'" target="_blank">'.$matches['value'].'</a>';
        // add id of each user in array
        case 'user' : $users[] = (int) $matches['value']; return '%s';
        default : return $matches['match'];
    }
}

$users = array();
$replaceArr = array();

$subj = 'An image:[@img:1234567890], a user:[@user:1234567890] and a file:[@file:file_name-with.ext]';
// escape percentage signs to avoid complications in the vsprintf function call later
$subj = strtr($subj,array('%'=>'%%'));
$subj = preg_replace_callback('~(?<match>\[@(?<type>[^:]+):(?<value>[^\]]+)\])~',replace_shortcut,$subj);

if (!empty($users)) {

    // connect to DB and check users
    $query = "  SELECT `id`,`nick`,`date_deleted` IS NOT NULL AS 'deleted'
                FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN ('".implode("','",$users)."')";
    // query
    // ...
    // and catch results
    while ($row = $con->fetch_array()) {
        // position of this id in users array:
        $idx = array_search($row['id'],$users);
        $nick = htmlspecialchars($row['nick']);
        $replaceArr[$idx] = $row['deleted'] ?
            "<span class=\"user_deleted\">{$nick}</span>" :
            "<a href=\"users/{$row['id']}\">{$nick}</a>";
        // delete this key so that we can check id's not found later...
        unset($users[$idx]);
    }
    // in here:
    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        $replaceArr[$key] = '<span class="user_unknown">User'.$value.'</span>';
    }
    // replace each user reference marked with %s in $subj
    $subj = vsprintf($subj,$replaceArr);

} else {

    // remove extra percentage signs we added for vsprintf function
    $subj = preg_replace('~%{2}~','%',$subj);

}
unset($query,$row,$nick,$idx,$key,$value,$users,$replaceArr);

echo $subj;
```

Comment: That is a good point, I didn't even think about a string with multiples yet.

Comment: You might also wanna use `preg_replace_callback()` to reformat these values instead of just catching them witth `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
/\[@(\w+):([^]]*)\]/
```

`\[` escapes the `[` character (otherwise interpreted as a character set); `\w` means any "word" character, and `[^]]*` means any non-`]` character (to avoid matching past the end of the tag, as `.*` might). The parens group the various matched parts so that you can use `$1` and `$2` in `preg_replace` to generate the replacement text:

```
echo preg_replace('/\[@(\w+):([^]]*)\]/', '$1 $2', '[@link:abcdef]');
```

prints `link abcdef`